VBA: How to convert Function argument to String?
I am using a measurement software at work that uses VB scripts.
I want to modify it and for that I need to know what arvalues(2) is.
So, it is a Variant and is used as follows (code excerpts):
Option Explicit

Dim oDS As CamDatasource
Function PXLoadForm(ViewId As Long, FrameId As Long, arvalues() As Variant) As Long

Set oDS = arvalues(2)

'and is then used as
Test = oDS.Parameter(Testparameter)

I tried to simply output it as a string in a a.WriteLine CStr(arvalues(2)) but that did not work.
Unfortunately the program does not output debug info so I do not know why it fails. But the WriteLine as such works (tested it in other places).
I am thinking that the Variant needs to be read more like an array or something.
Does anybody know if this is the case and/or how to do it?
Thank you very much
Alex
EDIT:
So, first test results:
TypeName(arvalues(2)) returns ICamDataSource.
Looking at the Object Browser I see ArrayOfParameters for CamDatasource
Property ArrayOfParameters(Codes As Long, Num As Long, [Options As ArrayOptions = camAutoIncrementRecord], [Record As Long], [Entry As Long])
    Member of CAMSRCLib.CamDatasource
    property ArrayOfParameters

with Record
    Class Record
    Member of ADODB

And Record showing


Firstly, try Debug.Print TypeName(arvalues(2)). What does it show? Then, Set oDS = ... is used only for objects. If arvalues(2) is really an object (CamDatasource), how to be converted in a string? I am not sure I can understand what you try doing...

@FaneDuru: I will try to debug.print to a file. Maybe it will work. What I am trying to do is see what the syntax for arvalues(2) is so I can point oDS to a different source file. But for that I need to know what kind of argument it needs. I thought that as a Datasource it should need a filename and potentially some properties. But I do not know for sure. So if it is an object, can I somehow see what the object looks like? It must be/contain a filename or something like that because the oDS.Parameters are read from a local file.

Would be very helpful if you could tell us which software are you using (what is the host program) and what the type CamDatasource is.

Can I somehow check what the type of CamDatasource is (using debug.print)?

Why "debug.print to a file"? What application do you use? What kind of object is the declared CamDatasource?

If the line 'Dim oDS As CamDatasource' is accepted by the VBA compiler, it indicates that 'CamDatasource' is either an existing object class or a user-defined data type.

@taller, where could I look that up though? I do not have access to the source code, only that one script. Can I check that from within the script? It is not defined within that script.

Have you tried to debug and look at the object?

I performed debugging to an external file (Debug.Print will not show anything) and added the information as EDIT to the first post.
Is there any way of printing arvalues(2) to the debug file? So show the value of it so I can simply reproduce it?

Anybody, please?
